# Pandas select rows which root count 3 times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file':['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9','f10','f11','f12'],
    'root':['root1','root1','root1','root2','root2','root2','root3','root4','root5','root6','root6','root6'],
})
```

I need output like this:

```
    file    root
0   f1  root1
1   f2  root1
2   f3  root1
3   f4  root2
4   f5  root2
5   f6  root2
9   f10 root6
10  f11 root6
11  f12 root6
```

Because root1 / root2 / root3 count 3 times in column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)

The API for this is the `groupby` object's `filter` method.
[see also Split-Apply-Combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration)

```
df.groupby('root').filter(lambda x: x.size > 2)

   file   root
0    f1  root1
1    f2  root1
2    f3  root1
3    f4  root2
4    f5  root2
5    f6  root2
9   f10  root6
10  f11  root6
11  f12  root6
```

Pass a callable to `filter` that accepts a dataframe as it's argument and returns a boolean.  `groupby` then returns only those groups in which the callable returned `True`

Comment: use map + value_counts 
seems faster

Comment: I'm certain I could come up with several methods that are faster.  But this is the simplest straight forward way to do it as this method was created by the devs expressly for this purpose.  And, for 99% of users, the speed will not be an issue.  Correction, maybe 95% of users.

Comment: It seemed slower but it really isn't, this was simply due to the comparison> 2 instead of == 3

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform('count')` on `groupby`:

```
df[df.groupby('root')['file'].transform('count').eq(3)]
```

Output:

```
   file   root
0    f1  root1
1    f2  root1
2    f3  root1
3    f4  root2
4    f5  root2
5    f6  root2
9   f10  root6
10  f11  root6
11  f12  root6
```

Comment: use map + value_counts seems faster

Answer (score 1):

You coul do:

```
mask = (df.groupby('root').transform('count').eq(3)).squeeze()
print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   file   root
0    f1  root1
1    f2  root1
2    f3  root1
3    f4  root2
4    f5  root2
5    f6  root2
9   f10  root6
10  f11  root6
11  f12  root6
```